# Angular JS multiple language translate

Tags: angularjs, translation

I'm new in Angular JS and I'd want to know which library is easier to implementation or most used to translate a website with Angular JS on your opinion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search will give you the answer. i18n is the most recommended.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n